# Does Libcurl support signature header

Tags: c++, c, http, curl, libcurl

I want to send a http message with a signature header. Some thing like that:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: server.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8
Signature: 42A424FB0C4938BBF08259514C64ABFC1E74C61F

any data
```

The signature header contains the 40-character hexadecimal representation (case 
insensitive) of `HMAC-SHA1 (Key, Text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't support that header specifically, but it supports that *you* insert that header in the request, using [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) as shown in the [httpcustomheader](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html) example.